# Can one use a correlated sub-query in Sybase ASE that has "TOP 1 column"?

Tags: sql, subquery, sap-ase, correlated-subquery

I tried to use a [proposed query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14859134/is-there-a-good-way-to-do-this-in-sql/14859539#14859539) on Sybase ASE 12, and it complained about syntax error.

```
SELECT 
    item, 
    ( SELECT TOP 1 tags.tag
      FROM #tags tags
        LEFT JOIN t o
          ON  tags.tag = o.tag
          AND o.item_id = n.item_id 
      WHERE o.tag IS NULL
      ORDER BY tags.tag
    ) 'tag',
    value  
FROM
    t_new n
```

ERROR: `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'top'.`

However, the same query worked when I replaced (`TOP 1 tag`... `ORDER BY tag`) with MAX():

```
SELECT 
    item, 
    ( SELECT max(tags.tag)
      FROM #tags tags
        LEFT JOIN t o
          ON  tags.tag = o.tag
          AND o.item_id = n.item_id 
      WHERE o.tag IS NULL
        --  ORDER BY tags.tag
    ) 'tag',
    value  
FROM
    t_new n
```

- Why is using (`TOP 1 tag`... `ORDER BY tag`) a problem in Sybase's correlated sub queries?
- Is there any fix to the original query that does NOT use min()/max()?

Comment: In Sybase, 'top' and 'order by' are mutually exclusive.  The order for top is determined by clustered indexes.  If there aren't clustered indexes, then the results can be unpredictable.  Also, I didn't think top was supported until ASE 12.5.3, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Also: "Adaptive Server Enterprise version 12.5.3 supports the top n clause in outer query select statements, but not in the select list of a subquery. This differs from Microsoft SQL Server. Any attempt to use the top n clause with Adaptive Server in a subquery yields a syntax error."  From the ASE 15.0.3 documentation here http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00641.1502/html/nfg1502/CHEHFFJJ.htm

Comment: @MichaelGardner - I think you're wrong on the first comment. Second comment should be an answer if you include the Sybase docs quote.

Comment: Yes, I was mistaken, ordering is only disallowed on updates/deletes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Adaptive Server Enterprise version 12.5.3 supports the top n clause in
>   outer query select statements, but not in the select list of a
>   subquery. This differs from Microsoft SQL Server. Any attempt to use
>   the top n clause with Adaptive Server in a subquery yields a syntax
>   error.

From the ASE 12.5.3 documentation [here](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.doc.ase_docs_12.5.3.newfeatures1253_rev/html/newfeatures1253_rev/newfeatures1253_rev11.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I know it is late but just for others TOP inside a subquery can be used in sybase latest version.